# Wpf Calendar Control Customization

Tags: wpf, calendar, customization

I have a calendar control (WPFToolkit) in a wpf form and I need to put a "Today" button in it.
Is there a way to di that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inherit from that control and override its default style? Put in that style "Today" button and subscribe to its Click event in OnApplyTemplate()...